# Integrate $\int \sqrt{1+\cos(t/2)} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am looking for a neat and smart way to do this.

I tried by substituting $u = 1+\cos(t/2)$

But I think its not the simplest way

Comment: You can use the half-angle identity $2 \cos^2(\frac{u}{2}) = 1 + \cos u$ to eliminate the radical.

Answer (score 4):

By the half-angle formulas,
$$ 1+\cos(t/2) = 2\cos^2(t/4),$$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int\sqrt{1+\cos(t/2)}\,dt&=&\sqrt{2}\int |\cos(t/4)|\,dt\\&=&C+8\sqrt{2}\left\lfloor\frac{t}{4\pi}\right\rfloor+\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}4\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\pi\left\{\frac{t}{4\pi}\right\}\right)&\text{if}&\left\{\frac{t}{4\pi}\right\}\in[0,1/2],\\8\sqrt{2}-4\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\pi\left\{\frac{t}{4\pi}\right\}\right)&\text{if}&\left\{\frac{t}{4\pi}\right\}\in[1/2,1].\end{array}\right.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

I've always had a terrible memory, so I just learned the double angle formula.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\int\sqrt{1+\cos(t/2)}dt&=&\int\sqrt{1+\cos(2\cdot\frac{t}{4})}dt\\
&=&\int\sqrt{1+(\cos^2(t/4)-\sin^2(t/4))}dt\\
&=&\int\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t/4)-1+\cos^2(t/4)}dt\\
&=&\int\sqrt{2\cos^2(t/4)}dt\\
&=&...
\end{array}$$
Obviously the next step is to make the substitution $u=t/4$